# how to take Snapshot from Usb camera using terminal

Tags: usb, 14.10, webcam, camera

so i am sure my device is reached since i tried 
lsusb

> Bus 003 Device 020: ID 1b3f:2002 Generalplus Technology Inc. 808
>   Camera #9 (web-cam mode)

i tried  uvccapture it uses the default cam (laptop's cam) not the usb connected one and it saves it to a specfied folder this is ok but i need the usb cam to take snapshot

i then tried cheese it makes the usb camera work but i have to manualy click on the button to save the pic however i need this automatically by the terminal like uvccapture

so ya what i need is i type in the terminal and automatically the usb cam takes a snapshot and save it to a specified folder

Comment: ffmpeg my also help, from this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/102755/how-do-i-use-ffmpeg-to-take-pictures-with-my-web-camera

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it what device to use.

```
-d<device>
          V4L2 Device (default is /dev/video0)
```

If the default is your built-in camera (and that is most likely since that one was present during install) you need to find out the device of your USB camera.

So do a

```
ls /dev | grep video
```

without the USB and then plug it in, wait a little bit and do the command again. There is likely a new device beginning with `video`. Use that to tell

```
uvccapture -d/dev/video1
```

where video1 is the new device you got.

Comment: it ouputs format asked unavailable get width 1280 height 720 ioctl querycontrol error 22